# Spring Batch- Xml based configuration performance over Java based

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to convert the spring batch configuration from xml based to annotation based.

Below is my xml based configuration.

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />
    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step will need a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="dbMapper" class="org.test.DBValueMapper">
   </bean>

    <bean id="dbMapperFlatfile" class="org.test.FlatFileRowMapper">
   </bean>

   <bean id="paramSetter" class="org.test.DBParamSetter">
   </bean>
   <bean id="dbReader" class="org.test.DBValueReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="paramSetter" ref="paramSetter"/>
        <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql" value="#{jobParameters['SQL_QUERY']}" />
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="dbMapper" />
        <property name="fetchSize" value="5000" />
    </bean>

<bean id="dbWriterIO" class="org.test.TemplateWritterIO"
        scope="step">
        <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
<!--        <property name="rptConfig" value="#{jobParameters['RPT_CONFIGVAL']}" /> -->
        <property name="headerCallback" ref="dbWriterIO" />
        <property name="footerCallback" ref="dbWriterIO" />
    </bean>

<batch:job id="fileGenJobNio">
        <batch:step id="fileGenJobStempNio">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="dbReader" writer="dbWriterNIO" 
                    commit-interval="5000">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

Below is the equivalent Java based configuration:

```
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @Import({ServiceConfiguration.class})
    public class SRBatchGenerator extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

        @Autowired
        private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;


        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;

        @Autowired
        private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

         @Autowired
         private DBValueMapper mapper;

         @Autowired
         private DbHelper dbhelper;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource datasource;

        @Bean
        public Step step(){
            return stepBuilders.get("step")
                    .chunk(5000)
                    .reader(reader())
                    //.processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer())
                    //.listener(logProcessListener())
                    .faultTolerant()
                    //.skipLimit(10)
                    //.skip(UnknownGenderException.class)
                    //.listener(logSkipListener())
                    .build();
        }


        @Bean
        public Job fileGeneratorJob(){
            return jobBuilders.get("fileGeneratorJob")
                    //.listener(protocolListener())
                    .start(step())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public DBValueMapper mapper(){
            return new DBValueMapper();
        }

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public DBValueReader3 reader(){
            String query="Select Test1,Test2,test3,test4 from RPt_TEST";
            DBValueReader3 dbread = new DBValueReader3();
            dbread.setSql(query);
            dbread.setRowMapper(mapper);
            dbread.setDataSource(datasource);
            return dbread;
        }

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public TemplateWritterIO writer(){
            TemplateWritterIO writer=new TemplateWritterIO();
            writer.setVelocityEngine(velocityEngine);
            return writer;
        }



        @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = 
                new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return  (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
        }

    }
```

When I execute my Job using xml based it took 27sec to write 1 Million record into Flat file.

But to write same 1 million record, Java based job took about 2 hours to write.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Can anyone help me or guide me why it is slow in Java based configuration.

Comment: While this shouldn't account for the entire difference, you are using a Map based job repository in the XML config, but a database one in the java config...

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response. But if you are take a look at the "createJobRepository()" I have override with MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean. So in XML as well as Java based it uses the same JobRepository

Comment: Sorry I missed that.  Have you spent any time profiling the app?  The only difference between java config and XML config is the way it's bootstrapped.  The rest is the same so I'd expect the only difference to be the startup (time until the job launched).

Comment: This is how I bootstrap the application.
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SRBatchGenerator.class);
   Job runJob=context.getBean("fileGeneratorJob",Job.class);
   JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
   jobLauncher.run(runJob,new JobParameters());
   
I will try to do profiling this. Meanwhile Do you see any pitfall in boot strapping  approach.

Comment: Nope.  That's what I'd expect.

Comment: HI Michael,
I did the analyze , in Xml Configuration reading data from DB and executing Mapping logic for chunck of 5000 records took only 2 sec. 
But in Java for the same step took 50 seconds for chunck of 5000 recods.
Could you help me to understand why it is taking more time in Java based and what could be the possible reson.
Thanks for your help

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what it's spending that time on.  Most profilers will let you see how long method calls take.  Where is that time being spent?  If you have a sample I can look at, post a github link.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did profiling the app I can see most of the time spend in executing the mapper and doget() method of JdbcCursorItemReader. Below is the git repository url of the project https://github.com/Enigma2506/Report . Again thanks for your help.